# GStreamer WebRTC DTLS connection closing immediately

Tags: openssl, webrtc, gstreamer

I am trying to connect to a remote WebRTC server using `webrtcbin` but when GStreamer attempts to open a connection, OpenSSL immediately throws a syscall error and restarts the connection. ICE negotiation is successful so I don't know what is causing the close.

Here is my log:

```
0:00:02.756141367 26063 0x7f3938002980 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:5542:_set_description_task:<webrtcbin0> Attempting to set remote answer in the have-local-offer state
0:00:02.756172515 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:5725:_set_description_task:<webrtcbin0> we are in ice controlling mode: true
0:00:02.756185680 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:165:transport_send_bin_change_state:<transportsendbin0> changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.756205508 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportreceivebin transportreceivebin.c:237:transport_receive_bin_change_state: changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.756229713 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4784:_update_transport_ptmap_from_media:<webrtcbin0> mapping sdp session level attributes to caps
0:00:02.756238921 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4786:_update_transport_ptmap_from_media:<webrtcbin0> mapping sdp media level attributes to caps
0:00:02.756260912 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4784:_update_transport_ptmap_from_media:<webrtcbin0> mapping sdp session level attributes to caps
0:00:02.756266583 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4786:_update_transport_ptmap_from_media:<webrtcbin0> mapping sdp media level attributes to caps
0:00:02.756536211 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:6549:on_rtpbin_request_aux_sender:<webrtcbin0> requesting aux sender for stream <transportstream0>
0:00:02.756668010 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:165:transport_send_bin_change_state:<transportsendbin0> changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.756682808 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportreceivebin transportreceivebin.c:237:transport_receive_bin_change_state: changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.756713195 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4963:_update_transceiver_from_sdp_media:<webrtcbin0> transceiver <webrtctransceiver0> direction change from none to inactive
0:00:02.756731359 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:301:_on_notify_dtls_client_status:<transportsendbin0> DTLS-SRTP encoder configured. Unlocking it and maybe changing state <dtlssrtpenc0>
0:00:02.756737531 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG     webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:274:maybe_start_enc:<transportsendbin0> Can't start DTLS yet because ICE is not connected.
0:00:02.756747820 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:165:transport_send_bin_change_state:<transportsendbin0> changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.756757909 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportreceivebin transportreceivebin.c:237:transport_receive_bin_change_state: changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.756776905 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4963:_update_transceiver_from_sdp_media:<webrtcbin0> transceiver <webrtctransceiver1> direction change from none to inactive
0:00:02.756782826 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:5385:_update_transceivers_from_sdp:<webrtcbin0> All mlines in bundle 0 are inactive. Blocking receiver
0:00:02.756805008 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:5780:_set_description_task:<webrtcbin0:sink_0> Connecting input stream to rtpbin with transceiver <webrtctransceiver0> and caps application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, packetization-mode=(string)1, sprop-parameter-sets=(string)"Z0LAH5WQBQBbv/BaAFe24CGgCAAAH0AAB1MEIA\=\=\,aMuPIA\=\=", payload=(int)127, seqnum-offset=(uint)17320, timestamp-offset=(uint)986581834, ssrc=(uint)2357747071, a-framerate=(string)30
0:00:02.756812242 26063 0x7f3938002980 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4522:_connect_input_stream:<webrtcbin0:sink_0> linking input stream 0
0:00:02.756887414 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:165:transport_send_bin_change_state:<transportsendbin0> changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.756910337 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:5780:_set_description_task:<webrtcbin0:sink_1> Connecting input stream to rtpbin with transceiver <webrtctransceiver1> and caps application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)OPUS, sprop-stereo=(string)1, encoding-params=(string)2, sprop-maxcapturerate=(string)48000, payload=(int)111, ssrc=(uint)575315586, timestamp-offset=(uint)923306429, seqnum-offset=(uint)17541
0:00:02.756917260 26063 0x7f3938002980 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4522:_connect_input_stream:<webrtcbin0:sink_1> linking input stream 1
0:00:02.757120523 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:165:transport_send_bin_change_state:<transportsendbin0> changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.757138327 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:165:transport_send_bin_change_state:<transportsendbin0> changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.757152764 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportreceivebin transportreceivebin.c:237:transport_receive_bin_change_state: changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.757181328 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcice gstwebrtcice.c:720:gst_webrtc_ice_set_remote_credentials:<webrtcbin0:ice> Setting remote ICE credentials on ICE stream 1 ufrag:vADx pwd:lBSY6uVL3+s0KRaiWEbi0s
0:00:02.757192699 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:165:transport_send_bin_change_state:<transportsendbin0> changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.757209531 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG   webrtctransportreceivebin transportreceivebin.c:237:transport_receive_bin_change_state: changing state: PLAYING => PLAYING
0:00:02.757235209 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcice gstwebrtcice.c:720:gst_webrtc_ice_set_remote_credentials:<webrtcbin0:ice> Setting remote ICE credentials on ICE stream 1 ufrag:vADx pwd:lBSY6uVL3+s0KRaiWEbi0s
0:00:02.757245589 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4692:_add_ice_candidates_from_sdp:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:1 1 UDP 4261412862 66.22.231.184 50004 typ host
0:00:02.757331541 26063 0x7f393c0af700 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:6829:on_rtpbin_new_sender_ssrc:<webrtcbin0> session 0 ssrc 2357747071 new sender ssrc
0:00:02.757360285 26063 0x7f393c0af700 LOG     webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:132:pad_block:<rtp_sink:proxypad7> blocking pad with data buffer: 0x7f38fc021c60, pts 1000:00:00.000000000, dts 1000:00:00.000000000, dur 99:99:99.999999999, size 14, offset none, offset_end none, flags 0x4040
0:00:02.757608343 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG    webrtcnicetransport nicetransport.c:250:_on_component_state_changed:<webrtcnicetransport0> 1 1 connecting
0:00:02.757620426 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG     webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:274:maybe_start_enc:<transportsendbin0> Can't start DTLS yet because ICE is not connected.
0:00:02.757636636 26063 0x7f3938002980 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4686:_add_ice_candidates_from_sdp:<webrtcbin0> Unknown mline 1, dropping ICE candidates from SDP
0:00:02.757643149 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2015363327 192.168.1.100 41531 typ host
0:00:02.757806336 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:2 1 TCP 1015021823 192.168.1.100 9 typ host tcptype active
0:00:02.757817968 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:3 1 TCP 1010827519 192.168.1.100 49019 typ host tcptype passive
0:00:02.757964895 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:4 1 UDP 2015363583 fe80::60d2:bcaa:a0ed:bd8e 41883 typ host
0:00:02.758112975 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:5 1 TCP 1015022079 fe80::60d2:bcaa:a0ed:bd8e 9 typ host tcptype active
0:00:02.758123144 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:6 1 TCP 1010827775 fe80::60d2:bcaa:a0ed:bd8e 42509 typ host tcptype passive
0:00:02.758276032 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:7 1 UDP 1679819007 <MY_IP> 41531 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 41531
0:00:02.758435463 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:8 1 TCP 847249663 <MY_IP> 9 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 9 tcptype active
0:00:02.758449559 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:9 1 TCP 843055359 <MY_IP> 49019 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 49019 tcptype passive
0:00:02.758605644 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:10 1 UDP 505430271 34.203.251.218 53142 typ relay raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 41531
0:00:02.758756238 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:4665:_add_ice_candidate:<webrtcbin0> adding ICE candidate with mline:0, a=candidate:11 1 UDP 337641727 34.203.251.246 57171 typ relay raddr 192.168.1.100 rport 9
0:00:02.758908705 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:1513:_check_if_negotiation_is_needed:<webrtcbin0> checking if negotiation is needed
0:00:02.758920327 26063 0x7f3938002980 LOG                webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:1663:_check_if_negotiation_is_needed:<webrtcbin0> no negotiation needed
0:00:02.758939443 26063 0x7f3938002980 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:1409:_update_ice_connection_state_task:<webrtcbin0> ICE connection state change from new(0) to checking(1)
0:00:02.758950364 26063 0x7f3938002980 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:1446:_update_peer_connection_state_task:<webrtcbin0> Peer connection state change from new(0) to connecting(1)
2022-07-18T16:52:37.306172Z TRACE tuxphones::discord::websocket: OpCode15(OpCode15 { any: 100 })
0:00:02.944151513 26063 0x7f393c002180 DEBUG              webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:6504:on_rtpbin_request_pt_map:<webrtcbin0> getting pt map for pt 127 in session 0
0:00:02.944183533 26063 0x7f393c002180 WARN               rtpsource rtpsource.c:1581:rtp_source_get_new_sr: no clock-rate, cannot interpolate rtp time for SSRC 2357747071
0:00:02.944317856 26063 0x7f393c002180 LOG     webrtctransportsendbin transportsendbin.c:132:pad_block:<rtcp_sink:proxypad11> blocking pad with data buffer: 0x7f38740a9d80, pts 99:99:99.999999999, dts 99:99:99.999999999, dur 99:99:99.999999999, size 80, offset none, offset_end none, flags 0x0
0:00:02.989297331 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG    webrtcnicetransport nicetransport.c:250:_on_component_state_changed:<webrtcnicetransport0> 1 1 connected
0:00:02.989363395 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG                dtlsdec gstdtlsdec.c:742:gst_dtls_dec_fetch_connection: fetching 'rtp_0_24878607' from connection table, size is 1
0:00:02.989445901 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG                dtlsenc gstdtlsenc.c:415:src_activate_mode:<dtlsenc0> src pad activating in push mode
0:00:02.989748461 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG                dtlsenc gstdtlsenc.c:362:gst_dtls_enc_change_state:<dtlsenc0> starting connection rtp_0_24878607
0:00:02.989765894 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> initial state set: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1110|0 before SSL initialization
0:00:02.989781273 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> poll: before handshake: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1110|0 before SSL initialization
0:00:02.989811801 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 6
0:00:02.989889538 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1262:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: Timeout set
0:00:02.989897102 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:454:gst_dtls_connection_check_timeout_locked:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> waiting for 999993 usec
0:00:02.989996670 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 49
0:00:02.990003993 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1288:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: MTU query, returning 0...
0:00:02.990009374 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 49
0:00:02.990015625 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 49
0:00:02.990023330 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 42
0:00:02.990030343 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 49
0:00:02.990037777 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1277:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: pending write
0:00:02.990050411 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1199:bio_method_write:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: writing 255
0:00:02.990060450 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG                dtlsenc gstdtlsenc.c:666:on_send_data:<dtlsenc0> sending data from rtp_0_24878607 with length 255
0:00:02.990075639 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1285:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: flushing
0:00:02.990083032 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1199:bio_method_write:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: writing 86
0:00:02.990089745 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG                dtlsenc gstdtlsenc.c:666:on_send_data:<dtlsenc0> sending data from rtp_0_24878607 with length 86
0:00:02.990096478 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1285:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: flushing
0:00:02.990103762 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1220:bio_method_read:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: EOF
0:00:02.990118269 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> poll: after handshake: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1001010|c SSLv3/TLS write client hello
0:00:02.990125372 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1078:openssl_poll:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> do_handshake encountered potential BIO error
0:00:02.990132656 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1023:handle_error:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> OpenSSL reported a syscall error. flow_return=0
0:00:02.990134720 26063 0x7f3870008580 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3395:gst_base_sink_default_event:<nicesink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
0:00:02.990143136 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> first poll done: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1001010|c SSLv3/TLS write client hello
0:00:02.990220221 26063 0x7f3870008580 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:454:gst_dtls_connection_check_timeout_locked:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> waiting for 999672 usec
0:00:02.990256009 26063 0x7f3938002980 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:1409:_update_ice_connection_state_task:<webrtcbin0> ICE connection state change from checking(1) to connected(2)
0:00:02.990261359 26063 0x7f39000c42a0 DEBUG    webrtcnicetransport nicetransport.c:250:_on_component_state_changed:<webrtcnicetransport0> 1 1 ready
0:00:02.990292528 26063 0x7f3938002980 INFO               webrtcbin gstwebrtcbin.c:1409:_update_ice_connection_state_task:<webrtcbin0> ICE connection state change from connected(2) to completed(3)
0:00:03.007094132 26063 0x7f393c0af520 LOG     webrtctransportreceivebin transportreceivebin.c:106:pad_block:<queue4:src> blocking pad with data buffer: 0x7f38fc02b7e0, pts 0:00:01.272658000, dts 0:00:01.272658000, dur 99:99:99.999999999, size 1280, offset none, offset_end none, flags 0x40
0:00:03.990047625 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1262:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: Timeout set
0:00:03.990085276 26063 0x7f393c001980 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:454:gst_dtls_connection_check_timeout_locked:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> waiting for 1999944 usec
0:00:03.990112788 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 49
0:00:03.990122406 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1294:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: unhandled ctrl, 49
0:00:03.990132736 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1277:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: pending write
0:00:03.990147764 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1199:bio_method_write:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: writing 255
0:00:03.990159867 26063 0x7f393c001980 DEBUG                dtlsenc gstdtlsenc.c:666:on_send_data:<dtlsenc0> sending data from rtp_0_24878607 with length 255
0:00:03.990190374 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1285:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: flushing
0:00:03.990200073 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1199:bio_method_write:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: writing 86
0:00:03.990206765 26063 0x7f393c001980 DEBUG                dtlsenc gstdtlsenc.c:666:on_send_data:<dtlsenc0> sending data from rtp_0_24878607 with length 86
0:00:03.990215191 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1285:bio_method_ctrl:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: flushing
0:00:03.990224479 26063 0x7f393c001980 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:402:handle_timeout:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> handle timeout returned 1, is_alive: 1
0:00:03.990246400 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> handling timeout before poll: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1010|c SSLv3/TLS write client hello
0:00:03.990258753 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> poll: before handshake: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1010|c SSLv3/TLS write client hello
0:00:03.990278661 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1220:bio_method_read:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> BIO: EOF
0:00:03.990293068 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> poll: after handshake: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1001010|c SSLv3/TLS write client hello
0:00:03.990299921 26063 0x7f393c001980 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1078:openssl_poll:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> do_handshake encountered potential BIO error
0:00:03.990307114 26063 0x7f393c001980 DEBUG         dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:1023:handle_error:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> OpenSSL reported a syscall error. flow_return=0
0:00:03.990318235 26063 0x7f393c001980 LOG           dtlsconnection gstdtlsconnection.c:853:log_state:<GstDtlsConnection@0x7f393c00d300> handling timeout after poll: role=client buf=((nil):0/0) 1001010|c SSLv3/TLS write client hello
```

Here is my offer SDP:

```
v=0
o=- 7496777322085302825 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=ice-options:trickle
a=group:BUNDLE video0 audio1
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 127 96 97 98 99
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=ice-ufrag:7Ai78uOfSk+sob3EEtpVRvEKVhoSEfIR
a=ice-pwd:L/WUgMBnL1EXh2I7c9Gy71Gk52qCfClr
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=framerate:30
a=fmtp:127 packetization-mode=1;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAH5WQBQBbv/BaAFe24CGgCAAAH0AAB1MEIA==,aMuPIA==
a=rtpmap:96 red/90000
a=rtpmap:97 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:98 apt=96
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=127
a=ssrc-group:FID 2357747071 974312279
a=ssrc:2357747071 msid:user2626377030@host-e8949c15 webrtctransceiver0
a=ssrc:2357747071 cname:user2626377030@host-e8949c15
a=ssrc:974312279 msid:user2626377030@host-e8949c15 webrtctransceiver0
a=ssrc:974312279 cname:user2626377030@host-e8949c15
a=mid:video0
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F8:61:CF:F1:E4:50:9B:49:E1:E6:36:5A:81:F9:94:D2:BF:E0:42:78:AF:EE:A5:2A:04:AC:93:8D:61:D3:E3:F5
a=rtcp-mux-only
m=audio 0 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=setup:actpass
a=ice-ufrag:7Ai78uOfSk+sob3EEtpVRvEKVhoSEfIR
a=ice-pwd:L/WUgMBnL1EXh2I7c9Gy71Gk52qCfClr
a=bundle-only
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:111 OPUS/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 sprop-stereo=1;sprop-maxcapturerate=48000
a=ssrc:575315586 msid:user2626377030@host-e8949c15 webrtctransceiver1
a=ssrc:575315586 cname:user2626377030@host-e8949c15
a=mid:audio1
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F8:61:CF:F1:E4:50:9B:49:E1:E6:36:5A:81:F9:94:D2:BF:E0:42:78:AF:EE:A5:2A:04:AC:93:8D:61:D3:E3:F5
a=rtcp-mux-only
```

Here is my generated answer:

```
v=0
o=- 1420070400000 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS *
a=group:BUNDLE video0 audio1
m=video 50004 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 127 99
c=IN IP4 66.22.231.184
a=fmtp:127 x-google-max-bitrate=2500;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=fmtp:99 apt=127
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=mid:video0
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:50004
a=setup:passive
a=inactive
a=ice-ufrag:vADx
a=ice-pwd:lBSY6uVL3+s0KRaiWEbi0s
a=fingerprint:sha-256 4A:79:94:16:44:3F:BD:05:41:5A:C7:20:F3:12:54:70:00:73:5D:33:00:2D:2C:80:9B:39:E1:9F:2D:A7:49:87
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 4261412862 66.22.231.184 50004 typ host
m=audio 50004 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
c=IN IP4 66.22.231.184
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1;usedtx=1
a=maxptime:60
a=rtpmap:111 opus/90000
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=mid:audio1
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:50004
a=setup:passive
a=inactive
a=ice-ufrag:vADx
a=ice-pwd:lBSY6uVL3+s0KRaiWEbi0s
a=fingerprint:sha-256 4A:79:94:16:44:3F:BD:05:41:5A:C7:20:F3:12:54:70:00:73:5D:33:00:2D:2C:80:9B:39:E1:9F:2D:A7:49:87
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 4261412862 66.22.231.184 50004 typ host
```

I have also attached a screenshot of a Wireshark capture of the network activity (for a different session, but still the same result).
[image: Wireshark capture]

Here's the actual capture file: [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u9ShyEWyLv4U8aitN_PGBv2AqQhbSvlO/view?usp=sharing)

Here's my GStreamer pipeline:
[image: Pipeline]
I can post the SVG if needed.

Comment: Have you tried other WebRTC Agents? Just to quickly debug I would see if you could connect another.

Comment: Looking at the DTLS Handshake I believe the discord server isn't accepting the client certificate (and keeps retransmitting) not exactly sure. Would you mind sharing the PCAP? Another debugging idea would be using ECDSA (instead of RSA). Looking at the size of the certificate message that could be a problem?

Comment: @SeanDuBois I added the capture file, but how would I go about changing the key scheme? As far as I know GStreamer manages all of that stuff under-the-hood.

Comment: Thank for sharing! The issue is actually backwards, discord is accepting the ClientHello but GStreamer isn't accepting the DTLS packets. I believe the error you are seeing is OpenSSL requesting a retry (from timeout). My guess is that GStreamer is completely ignoring the packets OR it doesn't support DTLS v1.2 (and discord requires it)

Comment: What version of GStreamer and OpenSSL are you using? Would be worth upgrading to the latest. If that doesn't work would it be that hard to hook up to Pion (happy to help) that uses all the latest features when it comes to DTLS and SRTP

Comment: Also GStreamer does use RSA https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/master/ext/dtls/gstdtlscertificate.c#L221 might be a problem. Also the SRTP ciphers only use https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/ca8068c6d793d7aaa6f2e2cc6324fdedfe2f33fa/ext/dtls/gstdtlsagent.c#L200 see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=713701

Comment: I have GStreamer 1.20.3 and OpenSSL 1.1.1q. I'll post the pipeline that I'm using so you can have a bigger picture on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Great! I think GStreamer is a great choice to use for the final product, I just need a pcap of a working handshake so we can compare. Cant get server logs so this is the best debugging idea I got :)

Comment: How do you recommend I create a working handshake? The code that made this is pretty specialized to connecting to Discord so I'm not sure if I should try to adapt that or make a standalone GStreamer app specifically for testing. For more context my app is written in Rust, I see that Pion is a Go library so I don't know if that changes things.

Comment: I just found [webrtc-rs](https://github.com/webrtc-rs/webrtc) which I may be able to integrate into a new gstreamer plugin using [this guide](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/-/tree/main/tutorial) so that may be an alternative solution.

Comment: Can you just extract the Offer/Answer and attempt to connect? You don’t need to build the full app, just see if you can connect

Comment: As in I should attempt to connect to Discord or to some other service? If I'm connecting to Discord, what library should I use to connect?

Comment: Any library that you feel comfortable with (webrtc-rs, aiortc, pion etc..) I just want to compare a working handshake against this non-working one. I can diff the handshakes and see where they diverge.

Comment: I made my own library here https://github.com/ImTheSquid/gst-webrtcredux/tree/bin but now I'm having issues with the ICE connection failing.

Comment: I also created a dedicated question since a decent amount of the output changed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73262095/webrtc-ice-connection-failing-with-valid-ice-servers-and-candidates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make [my own library](https://github.com/ImTheSquid/gst-webrtcredux) since `webrtcbin` uses outdated standards that prevent DTLS from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to post this question to either the GStreamer mailing list: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/lists/ or ask directly on their irc: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/dev/

You linked to the old separate repos of theirs - they merged it all into a mono repo: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer

BTW, there is also a new higher-level element for webrtc, the webrtcsink:
https://github.com/centricular/webrtcsink